# Is there a possibility to add variable extrusion width to models with different wall features? (Simplify3d)

Tags: creality-ender-3, simplify3d, underextrusion

I've got a problem with the new "thin features" -solution in S3D. The model I want to print has some tapered thin walls, but also some thicker parts. I want to use this option for filling the gaps usually occurring when the wall thickness is just slightly greater than a multiple of the extrusion width.

For example:

- Extrusion width: 0.48 mm
- Wall thickness: 2 mm

Printing my model with this option enabled just doesn't work properly. Now the entire print is massively under extruded, the shells can be peeled like an onion.

I wanted to enable this feature because the thin features must be pretty tough and I don't have a clue why it affects every feature in such an inconvenient way. I've made sure that the Nozzle isn't clogged, the temperatures and other settings are right and there are no other new options enabled.

My setup:

- Ender 3 Pro, direct drive
- ExWidth auto 0.48
- Speed 60 mm/s
- External thin feature: single extrusion
- Internal thin feature: single extrusion
- Material PETG
- default extrusion multiplier: 1

Is Simplify3D able to distinguish thin features from thick ones or to not under extrude every feature by enabling single extrusion gap filling?

Comment: Slic3r has a setting "Use adaptive slicing."  See if you have a similar setting for S3D.  While this setting varies layer height for the best print, it might affect extrusion width.

Comment: Your best option is to use a smaller nozzle for smaller line width.  Small nozzles also need adequate flow rate to prevent clogging.

Comment: @PerryWebb do you suggest to disable adaptive slicing, if enabled? (btw. change of nozzle is an option, yes - but not necessarily "the best", as we only assume what is behind the "direct drive" and how thin the walls could be, so smaller nozzle may help but still not resolve...). Jwagn, don't you have problems with retraction when printing very small amounts? - I mean wear of material by extruder gears, causing underextrusion?

Comment: Sounds like you can keep adaptive slicing on.